# Intel graphics installer for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I am using Dell Latitude E7440 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit and I am looking for Intel graphics installer.

Could somebody help me on this?

I found this link http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/intel-linux-graphics-driver-installer-1-0-5

and then it takes me to this link https://01.org/linuxgraphics/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.5-linux

and I am lost. I don't see a link to download the installer but the page says [image]

But I do not see any installer on that page.

Any help on this??

Answer (score 1):

Most Intel integrated cards don't require a driver to work. If you can get to Ubuntu Desktop then it means your card is working properly.

Comment: The problem is Ubuntu 14.04 is recognizing two external monitors as one. I want to use two monitors and after googling I found out that having Intel graphics driver might solve that problem..That is the reason I want to  install Intel graphics driver.

Comment: Wait... have you connected 2 monitors to your laptop? If so, did you try to disable your laptop's screen?

Comment: I connected my Dell Latitude E7440 to the Dell docking station  PR02X and connected two external monitors to the docking station. The displays shows only two monitors(built in display and one external monitor). Whatever is displayed on the first external monitor is displayed on the second external monitor also.

Comment: I see. Can you please open Terminal, type `xrandr` and paste its output here? (or in pastebin)

Comment: Thanks for your help. can I post this on monday? I just left from office. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Sure. No problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31187/discussion-between-javanoob-and-tildearrow).

Comment: Here is the link to the output of the command xrandr : http://pastebin.com/bz00p5zv